# udpsink0 Could not create socket on Android 10 emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm new to android app and GStreamer so please bear with me. Appreciate any guidance on resolving this.

After spending considerable amount of time I'm able to successfully run/port all [GStreamer tutorials](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/-/tree/master) on Pixel_3a_API_29 emulator on Android Studio Chipmunk Patch 1 with [GStreamer pre-built library](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.20.2/).

Now I'm trying to modify android-tutorial-2 with following pipeline to send the audio data over network stream but the `udpsink` is creating problem. I've confirmed it by replacing `udpsink` with `fakesink` and the pipeline runs fine.

```
const gchar *pipeline = "audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! rtpL16pay ! udpsink";
```

[udpsink fail error emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9gaQ.png)

I did some troubleshooting to find out what is the problem and am able find the error `gst_multiudpsink_start:<udpsink0> error: Could not create socket: Unable to create socket: Operation not permitted`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470367/socket-create-unable-to-create-socket-1-operation-not-permitted) thread but it is completely un-related compared to my environment.

```
2022-06-24 13:57:28.714 13587-13587/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 I/GStreamer: GStreamer initialization complete
2022-06-24 13:57:28.767 13587-13587/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 I/GStreamer: Activity created. There is no saved state, playing: false
2022-06-24 13:57:28.768 13587-13587/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.176483700 0x77698cb49d30 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:236:gst_native_init Created CustomData at 0x77698a063550
2022-06-24 13:57:28.768 13587-13587/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.176564000 0x77698cb49d30 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:238:gst_native_init Created GlobalRef for app object at 0x2cba
2022-06-24 13:57:28.768 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.177255400 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:163:app_function Creating pipeline in CustomData at 0x77698a063550
2022-06-24 13:57:28.770 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.179423700 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:206:app_function Entering main loop... (CustomData:0x77698a063550)
2022-06-24 13:57:28.771 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.179482100 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:51:attach_current_thread Attaching thread 0x776989f9e210
2022-06-24 13:57:28.771 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.179939100 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:143:check_initialization_complete Initialization complete, notifying application. main_loop:0x77698a07f8e0
2022-06-24 13:57:28.771 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 I/GStreamer: Gst initialized. Restoring state, playing:false
2022-06-24 13:57:28.771 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.180105000 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:279:gst_native_pause Setting state to PAUSED
2022-06-24 13:57:28.771 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 W/GStreamer+multiudpsink: 0:00:00.180351400 0x776989f9e210 ../gst/udp/gstmultiudpsink.c:1445:gst_multiudpsink_start:<udpsink0> error: Could not create socket: Unable to create socket: Operation not permitted
2022-06-24 13:57:28.771 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 W/GStreamer+basesink: 0:00:00.180394100 0x776989f9e210 ../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c:5879:gst_base_sink_change_state:<udpsink0> error: Failed to start
2022-06-24 13:57:28.772 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.180738700 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:91:set_ui_message Setting message to: Error received from element udpsink0: GStreamer encountered a general resource error.
2022-06-24 13:57:28.772 13587-13663/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/GStreamer+tutorial-2: 0:00:00.181023400 0x776989f9e210 C:/Sandbox/gst-docs-master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-2/jni/tutorial-2.c:91:set_ui_message Setting message to: Error received from element udpsink0: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.
2022-06-24 13:57:28.822 13587-13660/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_2 D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7769d889f7c0, tid 13660
```

Comment: Have you tried to set port different to the default one?

Comment: Yes, I tried a different port with the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a problem with the code but permission. I had no idea how the android apps work obviously,
Adding following in `AndroidManifest.xml` solved my problem.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Later I also found that there are other permission tags that might be useful if you are dealing with reading and writing from the media,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope this help someone beginner like me.

Comment: Mark it as accepted so that it can help others in the futures.